# Update a mutable List within a foreach loop scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to update a mutable list with the content of a directory in HDFS, I have the following code witch in spark-shell works but inside an script it doesn't:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil

var listOfFiles= scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()

val hdfs_conf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hdfs_conf)
    val sourcePath = new Path(filePath)  

 hdfs.globStatus( sourcePath ).foreach{ fileStatus =>
      val filePathName = fileStatus.getPath().toString();
      val fileName = fileStatus.getPath().getName();
      listOfFiles.append(fileName)
  } 

listOfFiles.tail
```

any help, when running it launches an exception telling that listOfFiles is empty.

Comment: What exception do you get when you write it in a scala file?

Comment: the exception is that the listOfiles is empty

Comment: Nothing wrong on scala aspect I guess, maybe check the hdfs.globStatus ( ... ) part again

Comment: Most probably your hdfc.globalStatus(sourcePath) is not returning anything

Comment: why is it that in spark-shell it works and in an script it doesn't?

Comment: is there any other way to store the content of the directory in the bufferList

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using mutable collection.

Try:

```
val listOfFiles = hdfs.globStatus(sourcePath).map{ fileStatus =>
      fileStatus.getPath().getName();
  }
```